# Seaborn relplot: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Tags: python, seaborn

```py
sns.relplot("Common wasp", "Total-IgE", data=data, hue='Serum')
```

throws

```py
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

[With this `DataFrame`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMMn9.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443583/seaborn-valueerror-zero-size-array-to-reduction-operation-minimum-which-has-no)