# can't use tightlayout without getting an error in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

In the following code, if I uncomment the line with the call to `tightlayout`, I get a crash in matplotlib.  I'll be grateful for any suggestion re. why this is happening.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
ax= fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 6, in 
plt.tight_layout()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 451, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1490, in tight_layout
gcf().tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2613, in tight_layout
kwargs = get_tight_layout_figure(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 303, in get_tight_layout_figure
kwargs = auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 84, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
bb += [ax.get_tightbbox(renderer, for_layout_only=True)]
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 4203, in get_tightbbox
bbox = a.get_tightbbox(renderer)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 286, in get_tightbbox
bbox = Bbox.intersection(bbox, clip_path.get_extents())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 603, in get_extents
return Bbox([xys.min(axis=0), xys.max(axis=0)])
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py", line 43, in _amin
return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

I'm using Python 3.8.5 with matplotlib 3.3.1 and CartoPy 0.18.0.

Comment: It's all OK on my machine. More info should be provided, i.e. error messages, S/W version, etc.

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.8 with CartoPy 0.18 and matplotlib 3.3.2

Comment: Can you provide us with the traceback?

Comment: Here's the traceback:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same configuration, and was able to reproduce your error. But after looking for similar tracebacks, I finally found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63640434/5405298), where upgrading Matplotlib from 3.3.1 to 3.3.2 have solved the issue.

So if you first run in a terminal (with pip or conda)

```
conda upgrade matplotlib
```

or

```
pip install matplotlib==3.3.2
```

Then, make sure Matplotlib was updated to 3.3.2 and run your script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
ax= fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which produced the desired out with effectively working `tight_layout()` on my machine.

Comment: Indeed, this did solve the problem.  Thanks so much!