# Getting this PYTHON value error inside docker container

Tags: python, image, dataframe

I am using this python pandas & dataframe_image package in this simple program. I am trying to export the dataframe output (df) to PNG file. But getting this error inside the docker container. But its working on machine.

Can anyone please help me on this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4))
>>> print(df)
          0         1         2         3
0  0.330808  0.781473  0.932547  0.440994
1  0.777121  0.101482  0.451317  0.020650
2  0.615397  0.973937  0.518510  0.454620
3  0.636042  0.009769  0.983006  0.618849
4  0.021588  0.276602  0.811048  0.928457
5  0.892482  0.355014  0.050483  0.275732
>>> import dataframe_image as dfi
>>> dfi.export(df, 'df_styled.png')
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_CA.UTF-8)
[1129/005716.614490:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: Connection refused
[1129/005716.834742:INFO:headless_shell.cc(616)] Written to file /tmp/tmprz2n4mrq/temp.png.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dataframe_image/_pandas_accessor.py", line 24, in export
    return _export(obj, filename, fontsize, max_rows, max_cols, table_conversion, chrome_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dataframe_image/_pandas_accessor.py", line 73, in _export
    img_str = converter(html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dataframe_image/_screenshot.py", line 168, in run
    img_str = self.finalize_image(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dataframe_image/_screenshot.py", line 159, in finalize_image
    mimage.imsave(buffer, img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1577, in imsave
    rgba = sm.to_rgba(arr, bytes=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 313, in to_rgba
    if norm and (xx.max() > 1 or xx.min() < 0):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 39, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

DBus is running on the VM. Getting this below error now.

```
 /etc/init.d/dbus status
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-11-30 01:43:57 UTC; 57s ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 957 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─957 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only


>>> import numpy as np
>>> import dataframe_image as dfi
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4))
>>> dfi.export(df, '/home/nr/testing/df_styled.png')
[1130/014613.802954:INFO:headless_shell.cc(616)] Written to file /tmp/tmp33yqzne1/temp.png.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dataframe_image/_pandas_accessor.py", line 24, in export
    return _export(obj, filename, fontsize, max_rows, max_cols, table_conversion, chrome_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dataframe_image/_pandas_accessor.py", line 73, in _export
    img_str = converter(html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dataframe_image/_screenshot.py", line 168, in run
    img_str = self.finalize_image(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dataframe_image/_screenshot.py", line 159, in finalize_image
    mimage.imsave(buffer, img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1577, in imsave
    rgba = sm.to_rgba(arr, bytes=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 313, in to_rgba
    if norm and (xx.max() > 1 or xx.min() < 0):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 39, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dataframe_image` needs `dbus` to be up and running to handle the headless program (browser?) and take snapshots. This is normally not done in Docker containers. You need to bring it up somehow, which normally is done by `systemd` in current distributions.

If this is a development container, you can just manually bring it up with `systemd` each time you start the container. If this needs to be solved completely, you'll need to re-think your `entrypoint`, whether installing and using `systemd` inside the container or looking at how it starts `dbus` and replicating it there.

Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813588/systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container

Comment: Could you please check my questions again? I missed out some points there. I added now.

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443583/seaborn-valueerror-zero-size-array-to-reduction-operation-minimum-which-has-no